# error when podman push image to AWS registry

Tags: fedora, amazon-ecr, podman

I'm using `fedora` with `podman` to `push`  a `image` to a aws registry

But I get this error,

> Error: writing blob: Post "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/": EOF

No issues withe the login:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region sa-east-1 | podman login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com

Login Succeeded!
```

But when I try to push

```
podman --log-level debug  push XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx
```

output:

```
INFO[0000] podman filtering at log level debug          
DEBU[0000] Called push.PersistentPreRunE(podman --log-level debug push XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx) 
DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated that overlay is supported 
DEBU[0000] Merged system config "/usr/share/containers/containers.conf" 
DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated that overlay is supported 
DEBU[0000] Using conmon: "/usr/bin/conmon"              
DEBU[0000] Initializing boltdb state at /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod/bolt_state.db 
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver overlay                   
DEBU[0000] Using graph root /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage 
DEBU[0000] Using run root /run/user/1000/containers     
DEBU[0000] Using static dir /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage/libpod 
DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp      
DEBU[0000] Using volume path /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes 
DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated that overlay is supported 
DEBU[0000] Set libpod namespace to ""                   
DEBU[0000] [graphdriver] trying provided driver "overlay" 
DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated that overlay is supported 
DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated that metacopy is not being used 
DEBU[0000] Cached value indicated that native-diff is usable 
DEBU[0000] backingFs=extfs, projectQuotaSupported=false, useNativeDiff=true, usingMetacopy=false 
DEBU[0000] Initializing event backend journald          
DEBU[0000] configured OCI runtime runc initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime runc: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] configured OCI runtime kata initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime kata: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] configured OCI runtime runsc initialization failed: no valid executable found for OCI runtime runsc: invalid argument 
DEBU[0000] Using OCI runtime "/usr/bin/crun"            
INFO[0000] Found CNI network podman (type=bridge) at /home/bruno/.config/cni/net.d/87-podman.conflist 
DEBU[0000] Default CNI network name podman is unchangeable 
INFO[0000] Setting parallel job count to 37             
DEBU[0000] Looking up image "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" in local containers storage 
DEBU[0000] Trying "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" ... 
DEBU[0000] Trying "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest" ... 
DEBU[0000] parsed reference into "[overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1000/containers]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b" 
DEBU[0000] Found image "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" as "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest" in local containers storage 
DEBU[0000] Found image "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" as "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest" in local containers storage ([overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1000/containers]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b) 
DEBU[0000] Pushing image XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx to XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx 
DEBU[0000] Copying source image [overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1000/containers]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b to destination image //XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest 
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf" 
DEBU[0000] Loading registries configuration "/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf" 
DEBU[0000] Found credentials for XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com in credential helper containers-auth.json in file /run/user/1000/containers/auth.json 
DEBU[0000] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d for sigstore configuration 
DEBU[0000]  Using "default-docker" configuration        
DEBU[0000]   Using file:///var/lib/containers/sigstore  
DEBU[0000] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in /etc/docker/certs.d/XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com 
DEBU[0000] Using blob info cache at /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb 
DEBU[0000] IsRunningImageAllowed for image containers-storage:[overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b 
DEBU[0000]  Using default policy section                
DEBU[0000]  Requirement 0: allowed                      
DEBU[0000] Overall: allowed                             
Getting image source signatures
DEBU[0000] Manifest has MIME type application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, ordered candidate list [application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws, application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json] 
DEBU[0000] ... will first try using the original manifest unmodified 
DEBU[0000] Checking /v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0000] GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ 
DEBU[0000] Ping https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ status 401 
DEBU[0000] HEAD https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0000] ... not present                              
DEBU[0000] exporting filesystem layer "6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" without compression for blob "sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" 
DEBU[0001] No compression detected                      
DEBU[0001] Compressing blob on the fly                  
DEBU[0001] Uploading /v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/           
DEBU[0001] POST https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/ 
Copying blob 6973a448ae32 [--------------------------------------] 8.0b / 137.4MiB
WARN[0001] failed, retrying in 1s ... (1/3). Error: writing blob: Post "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/": EOF 
DEBU[0002] Found credentials for XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com in credential helper containers-auth.json in file /run/user/1000/containers/auth.json 
DEBU[0002] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d for sigstore configuration 
DEBU[0002]  Using "default-docker" configuration        
DEBU[0002]   Using file:///var/lib/containers/sigstore  
DEBU[0002] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in /etc/docker/certs.d/XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com 
DEBU[0002] Using blob info cache at /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb 
DEBU[0002] IsRunningImageAllowed for image containers-storage:[overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b 
DEBU[0002]  Using default policy section                
DEBU[0002]  Requirement 0: allowed                      
DEBU[0002] Overall: allowed                             
Getting image source signatures
DEBU[0002] Manifest has MIME type application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, ordered candidate list [application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws, application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json] 
DEBU[0002] ... will first try using the original manifest unmodified 
DEBU[0002] Checking /v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0002] GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ 
DEBU[0002] Ping https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ status 401 
DEBU[0002] HEAD https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0002] ... not present                              
DEBU[0002] exporting filesystem layer "6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" without compression for blob "sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" 
DEBU[0003] No compression detected                      
DEBU[0003] Compressing blob on the fly                  
DEBU[0003] Uploading /v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/           
DEBU[0003] POST https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/ 
Copying blob 6973a448ae32 [--------------------------------------] 8.0b / 137.4MiB
WARN[0004] failed, retrying in 1s ... (2/3). Error: writing blob: Post "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/": EOF 
DEBU[0005] Found credentials for XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com in credential helper containers-auth.json in file /run/user/1000/containers/auth.json 
DEBU[0005] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d for sigstore configuration 
DEBU[0005]  Using "default-docker" configuration        
DEBU[0005]   Using file:///var/lib/containers/sigstore  
DEBU[0005] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in /etc/docker/certs.d/XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com 
DEBU[0005] Using blob info cache at /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb 
DEBU[0005] IsRunningImageAllowed for image containers-storage:[overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b 
DEBU[0005]  Using default policy section                
DEBU[0005]  Requirement 0: allowed                      
DEBU[0005] Overall: allowed                             
Getting image source signatures
DEBU[0005] Manifest has MIME type application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, ordered candidate list [application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws, application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json] 
DEBU[0005] ... will first try using the original manifest unmodified 
DEBU[0005] Checking /v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0005] GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ 
DEBU[0005] Ping https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ status 401 
DEBU[0005] HEAD https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0005] ... not present                              
DEBU[0005] exporting filesystem layer "6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" without compression for blob "sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" 
DEBU[0006] No compression detected                      
DEBU[0006] Compressing blob on the fly                  
DEBU[0006] Uploading /v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/           
DEBU[0006] POST https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/ 
Copying blob 6973a448ae32 [--------------------------------------] 8.0b / 137.4MiB
WARN[0006] failed, retrying in 1s ... (3/3). Error: writing blob: Post "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/": EOF 
DEBU[0007] Found credentials for XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com in credential helper containers-auth.json in file /run/user/1000/containers/auth.json 
DEBU[0007] Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d for sigstore configuration 
DEBU[0007]  Using "default-docker" configuration        
DEBU[0007]   Using file:///var/lib/containers/sigstore  
DEBU[0007] Looking for TLS certificates and private keys in /etc/docker/certs.d/XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com 
DEBU[0007] Using blob info cache at /home/bruno/.local/share/containers/cache/blob-info-cache-v1.boltdb 
DEBU[0007] IsRunningImageAllowed for image containers-storage:[overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b 
DEBU[0007]  Using default policy section                
DEBU[0007]  Requirement 0: allowed                      
DEBU[0007] Overall: allowed                             
Getting image source signatures
DEBU[0007] Manifest has MIME type application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, ordered candidate list [application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws, application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json, application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+json] 
DEBU[0007] ... will first try using the original manifest unmodified 
DEBU[0007] Checking /v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0007] GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ 
DEBU[0007] Ping https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/ status 401 
DEBU[0007] HEAD https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f 
DEBU[0007] ... not present                              
DEBU[0007] exporting filesystem layer "6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" without compression for blob "sha256:6973a448ae3253e9c587bc4d29346bf77ae9fa350693a81f1ee28cd07c13d92f" 
DEBU[0008] No compression detected                      
DEBU[0008] Compressing blob on the fly                  
DEBU[0008] Uploading /v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/           
DEBU[0008] POST https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/ 
Copying blob 6973a448ae32 [--------------------------------------] 8.0b / 137.4MiB
DEBU[0008] Looking up image "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" in local containers storage 
DEBU[0008] Trying "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" ... 
DEBU[0008] Trying "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest" ... 
DEBU[0008] parsed reference into "[overlay@/home/bruno/.local/share/containers/storage+/run/user/1000/containers]@9aca0d1dcdb72d44b90f4c02889c307d1c372078866121238bc2606f7e3a3f2b" 
DEBU[0008] Found image "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx" as "XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest" in local containers storage 
Error: writing blob: Post "https://XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/nginx/blobs/uploads/": EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a similar issue, and resolve it by creating the empty ECR repository from the console and then to podman push command works

Comment: That's it, you have to create the ECR repository before push.
edit: I was able to fix by doing what @ariel-jalil said

Answer (score 3):

In my case it's due to IAM user permission error. My IAM user does not have the ECR write permission. The issue resolved after attaching ECR writing permission.

So double check the IAM user IAM permission.