# ECR and Buildah push task using Tekton

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ecr, tekton, buildah

I would like to use the buildah task from Tekton hub in order to build and push to ECR. It seems like there's an issue with the ECR token provided in my previous task.

You can see the error in the image below: "`Error: writing blob: Post \"https://193583157031.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/test-public/blobs/uploads/\": EOF`"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoGWW.jpg)

I tried this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965330/error-when-podman-push-image-to-aws-registry) but it doesn't resolve my issue.

BR,
Pape Alioune

Comment: Please add error messages as text.

Comment: The error was mentioned above: Error: writing blob: Post \"https://193583157031.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/test-public/blobs/uploads/\": EOF